# Unable to auto mount a data disk from /etc/fstab but mounts with mount -a command

Tags: disk, automount

Here are the commands I ran:

```
~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1852
loop1     7:1    0 49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18596
loop2     7:2    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
sda       8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0 29.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part
└─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0   75G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   75G  0 part /mnt
sdc       8:32   0  128G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0  128G  0 part
```

as you see, *sdc1* is not mounted
then I run

```
dev-mio-admin@mio-vm:~$ sudo mount -a
```

and

```
dev-mio-admin@mio-vm:~$ lsblk
```

and we can see *sdc1* is mounted to */mnt/disk1*

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1852
loop1     7:1    0 49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18596
loop2     7:2    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
sda       8:0    0   30G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0 29.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part
└─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0   75G  0 disk
└─sdb1    8:17   0   75G  0 part /mnt
sdc       8:32   0  128G  0 disk
└─sdc1    8:33   0  128G  0 part /mnt/disk1
```

Here is the line in my */etc/fstab file*

```
UUID=1c0adda6-1cc1-450d-89ee-76d26d384b13  /mnt/disk1   ext4   defaults   0 1
```

Why wouldn't it get attached automatically?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Why would you use `/mnt/disk1` as mountpoint for one partition while using `/mnt` as mountpoint for another partition? Maybe `sdc1` was mounted on `/mnt/disk1` during boot but the mount was superseeded then by mounting `sbd1` on `/mnt`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are mounting /mnt and then /mnt/disk1 which are different drives. Sometimes it appears /mnt mounts first and then /mnt/disk1 second. However, in some cases it’s trying to mount /mnt/disk1 which fails. 
So I changed the mount point to /data/disk1 and all works fine now.

Thanks @mook765

Comment: It is a good practice to make different folders inside `/mnt/` as different mount points to different disks/partitions and not use `/mnt/` as a mount point. Just as it is a good practice not to keep your documents directly like this: `C:\My_Resume.docx`.